# Where can I find a list of intents for Samsung Galaxy specific system functions?

Tags: android, android-intent, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to turn the Power Saving Mode feature on and off on a Samsung phone. I believe this shouldn't require root access as NFC Task Launcher can already do this, so I believe it's most likely just an intent that is being called to toggle the setting on and off.

Is there like a resource somewhere which displays a list of available intents to control Samsung specific system functionalities?

If not, is it actually possible to work out what the intent is?

EDIT - just thought of something, does the operating system have a manifest file? If so, is this possible to access? Shouldn't it have a list of intents in there right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a system manifest.xml file. Try to pull out it from /system/framework/framework-res.apk and use apktool to extract the apk file.

Here is a sample from Google Standard JB https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-cts-4.2_r2/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick response. Quick (and probably stupid) question, how do I actually get to that directory? I've plugged my phone in but there doesn't seem to be a system folder. In fact, there doesn't seem to be any apk's so I'm not sure where all the apps are stored.

Comment: It seems you are browsing your phone storage. You have to use ADB to connect your phone. Please refer to this page:http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html
However I think  you should have known this since you are asking some development questions, forgive me if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. I don't have much experience with Android programming. And for this task, I'm actually using Tasker to accomplish. But I'll have a look at ADB - however, looking around, it seems that I need root access to look at the system manifest unfortunately.

Comment: No you don't. /system/framework directory is read-able for everyone. And if you are using GalaxyNexus, I have help to get the xml file from my phone since you are so new to this ADB stuff.

Comment: thanks, the XML file is probably not useful for me cause it's the generic google manifest (the features I'm looking for are samsung specific) but I think using the ADB is the way to go, I'll read up on it and see if I can get it to connect to my phone and drag the XML file out.

Comment: Took ages, but I finally managed to get the manifest out (couldn't figure out how to get apktools to work) but yeah it doesn't look like the power saving function is in an intent (or if it is, it's probably called something obscure). Oh well, at least I learnt a lot today.

Comment: Good for you. And I think this kind of option will be stored in the Settings.System.XXX filed of the settings database. If you have the rooted device you can have a look at the file in the /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db stuff to find if there is something you are interested in.